# How do I retrieve the posts on a Facebook page using the Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to use Facebook's Graph API to retrieve the official posts from a given page. This means that the wall posts must be the one's made by the page's administrators and must exclude comments made on the posts. I'm aware that the base URL for the Graph API is `http://graph.facebook.com/`, but I'd like to use it without an access token. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**No**. You can't retrieve the posts using a given page without an *Access Token*.

You can retrieve posts by performing a GET request to the following end point (and of course using a valid Access Token):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/posts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You can also choose particular field(s) by specifying them in the URL. For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/posts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
&fields=message,type,likes
```

You can try out [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=seewaymore/feed?fields=message,type) in the Facebook Graph API explorer.